# Facebook Registration plugin ask for permissions to Post on timeline

Tags: facebook, xfbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the FB registration plugin to register users (Since I want a unique mysite_username for each user) But this does not allow me to access permissions to post on the users timeline like the FB login button.
I would like to know some standard technique to "Connect" my users with their facebook timeline so that they can choose to post the achievements they obtain on my website onto their facebook timeline!

Something like the [FBML Promt permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/prompt-permission/) but Its getting deprecated so I'm NOT really sure about using that. But smething like that would definitely help!!

Glad to accept the most suitable answer!
Adit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use FB.login from the JavaScript SDK, and specify the permissions you want in the scope parameter.

Comment: Hey I may be a bit late but I used your advice and used the Javascript SDK .
The registration plugin did not allow any modifications at all!